# How do I use the AdagradDAOptimizer Optimizer by using tf.compat.v1.train?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I tried using the AdagradDAOptimizer for my model but I got an error while I did the same thing to the ProximalAdaGrad Optimizer class. I did not get an error for that one so I am confused as to what I am doing wrong.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

start_time = time.time()



data = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle Boot']

train_images = train_images/255.0

test_images = test_images/255.0

optimizer1 = tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradDAOptimizer(0.001)

model = keras.Sequential([
                           keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
                           keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="softsign"),
                           keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer1, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc1 = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print("Test acc is:", test_acc1)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-bdc36910ec8c>", line 11, in <module>
    data = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/module_wrapper.py", line 193, in __getattr__
    attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1823, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'AttributeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1132, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 358, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1448, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Not sure why it says that "tensorflow_core.estimator" does not exist. It was there for the others but not now. I am using Google Colab if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your tensorflow version, most likely you need to update or clean install.You can check the version with:

```
print(tf.__version__)
```